# test mobile app on several mobiles (various screens)

Tags: testing, expo

I created an app with expo (react native) works fine on my mobile, I would like to test it on several mobiles.
is there a platform that allows me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **Android**, You can test with multiple devices using genymotion.

Official site for [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Device-specific management and use room for [genymotion](https://docops.ca.com/devtest-solutions/9-0/en/installing/setting-up-the-mobile-testing-environment/using-genymotion)

For **iOS**, you can use xcode to select and run for that device. Or you can connect the sill device to your computer and use it.

Simulator is in quotes here since this will create an actual app on your phone; it’s no longer a simulation. Open up a project in Xcode and click on the device near the Run ▶ button at the top left of your Xcode screen.

[image]

Plug your iPhone into your computer. You can select your device from the top of the list.

[image]